# Where are the missing airline_ontime_data and weather_geo (should be under samples) in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I just started GCP learning, can any tell me how can I load a specific public dataset into the bigquery, for example, `airline_ontime_data`, `weather_geo`, etc.? Below is the list showing here:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Initially I din't see the dataset mentioned by Guillem Xercavins under a "bigquery-samples" dataset either.

When I did a search in the Resource, it didn't find something called `bigquery-samples`

[image]

But, after I came back in 5 minutes, some datasets show up under `bigquery-samples` including `airline_online_data` and `weather_geo`:

[image]

I hope this helps to readers in the future: All you need is be patient and the magic will happen.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "load"? Note: Once you added the public dataset it's available for you to query

Comment: Thanks, I just want to use the public dataset in BigQuery, I don't see the mentioned datasets in BigQuery, thinking maybe there is some sort of "loading" step missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `airline_ontime_data` and `weather_geo` datasets are hosted under the `bigquery-samples` project (instead of `bigquery-public-data`). You can click on `Resources`, `+ Add Data` and select `Pin a Project` so that it's visible in the navigation panel.

[image]

Example query (just 40kB processed) that you can try:

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT airline
FROM
  `bigquery-samples.airline_ontime_data.airline_id_codes`
WHERE
  airline != 'Description'
LIMIT
  1000
```

Comment: Thanks. OP updated, there is no bigqeury-samples here

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you way more up-to-date datasets than the ones on the previous answer:

```sql
SELECT MAX(FlightDate )
FROM `fh-bigquery.flights.ontime_201908` 

# 2019-06-30
```

```sql
SELECT MAX(date )
FROM `fh-bigquery.weather_gsod.all`  

# 2019-12-31
```

Comment: Thank you Felipe, seems to me that everyone can attach a public dataset to BigQuery? if yes, how? sorry for the silly question, I just started learning GCP